# My custom "filteritemTemplate" is not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, filtering

**when using "filteritemtemplate", i couldn't able to access function value inside the column.**

> sample which replicates my issue:

[stackblitz sample link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyoezd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Reproducing method:**

> 1.open stackblitz link
>
> 2.filter shopcountry column
>
> 3.you will see, filter value is not displayed

**I think this screenshot shows my issue:**

[image: here it goes to that function but value is not getting updated]

**But i can read the function  still not returning its value. i have attached screenshot here**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

whatever you want to fill you should just put it like this:

```
 <ng-template #filterItemTemplate let-data ><div> hii {{getval(data)}}</div></ng-template>
```

replace **hii** with your data

Comment: if i use like this,it just show that string only....it will not show that function value..

Comment: nooo, if i use #Template...it is not my custom filtertemplate